# Creating list of all elements fullfilling relation in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a relation grandpa(X,Y) and I'm trying to get list of all grandpa's in the known world **without using forall, findall and similar methods**

My attempt so far is:

```
find_grandpas(Tmp,List):-
    grandpa(New,_),
    not(member(New,Tmp)),
    find_grandpas([New|Tmp],List).

list_grandpas(List) :- find_grandpas([], List), print_list(List).
```

while checking stepswith *trace* I can see, that correct list is evaluated, but later it is lost. How can I construct some "cut" condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you build the right list but you need to tell where to stop. For example if we have as facts:

```
grandpa(a,_).
grandpa(b,_).
grandpa(c,_).
```

Eventually you will build list `[a, b, c]` and recursively try to find another solution there calling in the next iteration:

`grandpa(New,_)` will produce `a` but due to `not(member(New,Tmp))`this will fail, via backtracking it will try again with `b`... and `c` wher also fails. Then no choice points left and it completely fails. Soyou need to change to:

```
find_grandpas(Tmp,List):-
    (
       grandpa(New,_),
       not(member(New,Tmp)) ->
       find_grandpas([New|Tmp],List); List = Tmp 
    ).
```

This simply says try  `grandpa(New,_),not(member(New,Tmp))` if succeed I have something to add, add it and go on in recursion. If not then no more solutions so set `List = Tmp` and this succeeds returning the right list.
Example:

```
?- find_grandpas([],L).
L = [c, b, a].
```